# How to define the beginning and ending of paragraphs in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, paragraphs, context-mkiv

The manner of creating paragraphs in ConTeXt appears to differ from that in LaTeX. In LaTeX, one need only create an empty line between two paragraphs, and paragraphs are automatically created, e.g.:

```
This is a paragraph.

This is another paragraph.
```

From looking through the various ConTeXt manuals, including the LaTeX in Proper ConTeXt article, I have only found mention that paragraphs are formed in a different manner, but no mention of how to actually form them. Perhaps such information is regarded as too basic to bother explaining or too simple to appear in any of my searches? Of the limited sample code I have found, most rely on sections to form the boundaries between paragraphs. I have learned of the `\crlf` command, but this appears more as equal to `\\`, but I am unclear if it is meant to designate the end and beginning of a new paragraph.

How are paragraphs defined in ConTeXt?

Comment: Are you, by any chance, looking at how to **indent** paragraphs? `\setupindentation[medium,yes]`.

Comment: Specifically, the fact that in LaTeX, environments may provide a `\noindent`, and this may be overridden by adding an extra blank line after the paragraph to obtain an indent anyway; while ConTeXt is whitespace-agnostic in this, and requires you to use `\indentation` or setup `[indentnext=...]`. 
http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Indentation
The talk of ignored blank lines may have left you thinking that paragraphs are different, but it's indentation, really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Separated by empty lines**

```
This is a paragraph

This is another one
```

or

**Using the `\par` command**

```
This is a paragraph\par
This is another one\par
```

or

**Using the `\startparagraph` command**

```
\startparagraph
  This is a paragraph
\stopparagraph
\startparagraph
  This is another one
\stopparagraph
```

Comment: So, this is a very old answer, but where is ``\startparagraph`` defined? It does not seem to be included in recent TeX distributions.

Answer (score 4):

Paragraphs can be devided by an empty line or `\par`. `\crlf` (carriage return--line feed) is similiar to `\cr` (carriage return) or the double backslash. They do *not* create a new paragraph!